# How can I pass double quoted "--parameter value" strings in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, whitespace, quotes

**EDIT**: Question was marked as a duplicate, please observe that value is sent in a specific way with double quotes like **`"--parameter value" "--parameter2 value2"`** this question has not been asked and does not have an answer.

## Problem

If the parameters are given double quoted like `"--parameter value" "--parameter2 value2"`, how can I pass them so that an end script can take it as `--parameter value --parameter2 value`?

If I try `$@` (without double quotes) it only works if parameter values do not contain whitespaces. If I try `"$@"` it does not work at all. Please see the scenario below that explains the problem with three files.

### Real life scenario

1. GitHub action (`action.yml`) calls a `Dockerfile` with double quoted parameter name and value pairs  `"--parameter value" "--parameter2 value2"`
2. `Dockerfile` in its entry point calls a shell script expecting parameters as `--parameter value --parameter2 value2` (without double quotes per parameter name / value pair).

### Simplified scenario

There are three steps in the call flow: the `caller.sh`, `middleman.sh` and `script.sh`. And I'm only in control of the `middleman`.

[image]

#### Caller

The entrypoint script. It calls the `middleman` in specific way where each parameter name and value is double quoted together. **I cannot control the behavior of this script.**

So we could represent it with `caller.sh` that would look like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./middleman.sh "--parameter1 value" "--parameter2 'value with whitespace'"
```

#### Middleman

This is the middle layer that's supposed to take the parameters from the `caller` and translates them into expanded parameters as the `script` would expect.

`middleman.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./script.sh "$@"
```

This is where the problem lies as this does not work. I tried also with `$@` without double quotes but then it only works if parameter values contain white space. How can I have the right call here?

#### Script

The script that's supposed to take the parameters in a right way. It wants to receive parameters such as `--name value`.

It works by parsing the parameters as following and e.g. prints them:

`script.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do case $1 in
  --parameter1) FIRST_PARAM="$2"; shift;;
  --parameter2) SECOND_PARAM="$2"; shift;;
  *) echo "[script.sh] Unknown parameter passed: '$1'"; exit 1;;
esac; shift; done

echo "[script.sh] parameter1: $FIRST_PARAM, second parameter: $SECOND_PARAM"
```

I cannot modify this script.

### Run the test

`./caller.sh`

Answer (score 1):

> how can I pass them so that an end script can take it as --parameter value --parameter2 value?

Pass it normally:

```
./middleman.sh --parameter1 value --parameter2 'value with whitespace'
```

> How can I have the right call here?

The presented code is correct, just:

```
./script.sh "$@"
```

For more information research word splitting expansion and quoting in shell. It's not how you pass arguments, it's how you "forward" and "parse" them - and `"$@"` is the correct way.

Side note: `case` is special - the `$1` in `case $1 in` does **not** undergo word splitting, so there is no need to quote it. I like quote all expansions and would write `case "$1" in` anyway.

Check your scripts with shellcheck.net .

Aaaand [tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DarkredLikelySystemadministrator#main.sh).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! But I cannot change the behavior of `caller.sh`, it's static and it unfortunately always calls parameter name and value pairs in quotes. I updated the question with real life scenario. So how can I "normalize" those quoted parameters? Btw my question is closed because of duplicate. This problem has never been stated before...

Comment: ? You do not control github actions? `how can I "normalize" those quoted parameters?` Write a parser. Now you changed the quoting also. So write a parser - extract the string before first space and after first space, create from these two strings two arguments and pass them along

Comment: Thanks. A simple solution like parsing I could not come up with sticking with `$@`. And sorry for not being clear enough about the quotes. I'm using `action.yml` (own action) and it always call the Dockerfile using its `args` by quoting key / value parameter pairs.I came up with this solution to support both normal parameter input and double quoted it works fine: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/undergroundwires/b384e499fd8ba850df173b685b30e32c/raw/08fe82da0109c5c1a36e8eea68a5e122fe9f4b7a/middleman.sh . I'd appreciate feedback otherwise feel free to update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `I'd appreciate feedback` Nice script ;) I would merge it.